# Determine whether a conversion is valid before attempting to perform it

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have the following subroutine:

```
Private Sub MySub(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs) Handles Me.ControlAdded
    Try
        AddHandler CType(e.Control, MyDerivedControlType).selectionChanged, AddressOf MyEventHander
    Catch ' This just protects against other types of control being added to the group box
    End Try
End Sub
```

The intention is that an event handler is set for any control added to the form, but only if it's a certain kind of control — determined by what its most-derived type is.

*Putting overarching design concerns aside for the time being*, although this subroutine functions properly, when running the debugger the constant exceptions keep leaving messages in my "Immediate Window". It's annoying, and presumably throwing exceptions only to immediately re-catch them is wasteful.

Can I figure out whether the `CType` will succeed *before* attempting it? And thus avoid this exception-as-logic-flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [TryCast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx).

```
Private Sub MySub(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ControlEventArgs) Handles Me.ControlAdded
    Dim ctl = TryCast(e.Control, MyDerivedControlType)
    If (ctl IsNot Nothing) Then
        AddHandler ctl.selectionChanged, AddressOf MyEventHander
    End If
End Sub
```

`TryCast` will return `Nothing` if the cast isn't successful or it will return the object casted to the specified type.  I believe in C# this "try cast" would look like `var ctl = e.Control as MyDerivedControlType;`.

Comment: Excellent; that'll do it. And the "way" it casts is the same as with `CType`? No subtle differences?

Comment: Correct, it's the exact same under the covers, with only one exception; you cannot `TryCast` to a _value_ type.  You can only `TryCast` to a _reference_ type -- because the result needs to be able to be checked against `Nothing` to see if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Before your current line, you could use TryCast instead of the CType.  Use the result when adding the event if the result is not nothing.

Comment: There is no reason to do _both_ a `TryCast` and a `CType`.  Matter of fact Visual Studio's code analysis will probably alert you that you have needlessly converted the type multiple times.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I answered too fast and didn't consider updating the next line to use the result of TryCast if the result is not null.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the VB equivalent is, but in C# you can do this:

```
if (e.Control is MyDerivedControl)
{
    MyDerivedControl ctrl = (MyDerivedControl)e.Control;
}
```

**EDIT**: Here's the code in VB.NET

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is MyDerivedControl Then
    Dim derivedCtrl As MyDerivedControl = DirectCast(ctrl, MyDerivedControl)
End If
```

Comment: @ckittel: The condition will prevent the code from throwing an exception, because it will validate the control is of type MyDerivedControl before attempting to cast it. Also, (MyDerivedControl)ctrl & ctrl as MyDerivedControl as the same thing, just different flavors.

Comment: @ckittel: Well, hopefully you aren't the one who voted me down. :)

Comment: @ckittle: Where are the two type conversions? It's only cast once in either example. I think you're misreading the "is" as an "as" in the condition. The condition is checking the type, and the cast is converting the type.

Comment: For the `is` operator to work, it performs the work of a cast.  Visual Studio's static code analysis detects this exact code as a violation of [CA1800](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(DONOTCASTUNNECESSARILY);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true#Y424).  See the C# example there for this _exact_ situation (// The 'is' statement performs a cast operation.).

Comment: @ckittel: Interesting. It appears that you are correct. I appreciate you pointing that out.

Comment: No problem.  It's one of those little things that once you are wise to, you just tend to never forget.